# How to handle timeouts with httplib (python 2.6)?

Tags: python, httplib

I'm using httplib to access an api over https and need to build in exception handling in the event that the api is down.

Here's an example connection:

```
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('non-existent-api.com', timeout=1)
connection.request('POST', '/request.api', xml, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})
response = connection.getresponse()
```

This should timeout, so I was expecting an exception to be raised, and `response.read()` just returns an empty string.

How can I know if there was a timeout? Even better, what's the best way to gracefully handle the problem of a 3rd-party api being down?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but I would encourage you to try MECHANIZE: a higher level API that wraps around httplib and provides an easier way to use HTTP protocol in **python**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

urllib and httplib don't expose timeout. You have to include socket and set the timeout there:

```
import socket
socket.settimeout(10) # or whatever timeout you want
```

Comment: `socket.timeout` takes a non-negative floating point in seconds: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

Comment: Ahh yeah. I was just shooting from memory.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.  and yes, httplib does have a timeout since 2.6: http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection

Answer (score 13):

> Even better, what's the best way to gracefully handle the problem of a 3rd-party api being down?

what's mean API is down , API return http 404 , 500 ...

or you mean when the API can't be reachable ?

first of all i don't think you can know if a web service in general is down before trying to access it so i will recommend for first one you can do like this:

```
import httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google.com')  # I used here HTTP not HTTPS for simplify
conn.request('HEAD', '/')  # Just send a HTTP HEAD request 
res = conn.getresponse()

if res.status == 200:
   print "ok"
else:
   print "problem : the query returned %s because %s" % (res.status, res.reason)
```

and for checking if the API is not reachable i think you will be better doing a try catch:

```
import httplib
import socket

try:
   # I don't think you need the timeout unless you want to also calculate the response time ...
   conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('www.google.com') 
   conn.connect()
except (httplib.HTTPException, socket.error) as ex:
   print "Error: %s" % ex
```

You can mix the two ways if you want something more general ,Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks. The second approach is what I was looking for. However, it doesn't raise an exception when trying to connect to a non-existent domain.

Comment: are you sure because it should raise __socket.gaierror__ which is a subclass of __socket.error__ ???

Comment: and all the errors (i think) are catched using __except (httplib.HTTPResponse, socket.error)__ right ?

Comment: I replaced www.google.com with some non-existent domain name and ran it in a python shell. No exception gets raised. Hmmm...

Comment: try it without the try except and you will see that it raise error :)

Comment: @chipotle_warrior: it's weird because after creating a connection to some no existing url like this:  __conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('blahblah')__ and when you try to connect __conn.connect()__ then it should raise the exception __gaierror__ because __blahblah__ it's non-existing domain the __gaierror__ is raised by __socket.getaddrinfo()__ that it's called to get the ip of this url. This is the exception that should be raise : __gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known__ , hope you found out what's the problem :)

Comment: Makes sense. Doesn't seem to be the case though. I'll look around for another method.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found to be working correctly with httplib2. Posting it as it might still help someone :

```
    import httplib2, socket

    def check_url(url):
        h = httplib2.Http(timeout=0.1) #100 ms timeout
        try:
            resp = h.request(url, 'HEAD')
        except (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, socket.error) as ex:
            print "Request timed out for ", url
            return False
        return int(resp[0]['status']) < 400
```